# Nice Cyrillic font for Russian like in Tufte's books

Tags: fonts, tufte, cyrillic

I'm trying to find nice Cyrillic font. Actually I would like to see such beautiful fonts as in tufte-book.
My attempt is using following

```
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
```

But still it is far from ideal:

[image]

Would you advise me what kind of (Cyrillic) fonts should I use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2):

Font recommendations would be a bit off-topic here, but I see that you’re limiting yourself to legacy 8-bit fonts.  So what I can do is give you a method to use any modern font of your choice.

I don’t know which books or fonts you’re specifically thinking of, but if you have a PDF of the books you’re taking as a model, you can examine it to see which fonts it uses.

Your best bet is to compile with LuaLaTeX and use an OpenType or TrueType font.  Try the following template, changing the font and font features as needed:

```
\documentclass{book} % Or whatever is appropriate
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\babelprovide[main, import=ru]{russian}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
% Substitute your fonts of choice:
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}[Language=Default, Ligatures=Common]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont[russian]{sf}[Language=Default, Ligatures=Common]{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}
\babelfont[russian]{tt}[Language=Default]{CMU Typewriter Text}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Матема́тика}

Матема́тика (др.-греч. μᾰθημᾰτικά < μάθημα «изучение; наука»)---наука
об отношениях между объектами, о которых ничего не известно, кроме
описывающих их некоторых свойств,---именно тех, которые в качестве
аксиом положены в основание той или иной математической теории.
Исторически сложилась на основе операций подсчёта, измерения и
описания формы объектов.

\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Serif Sample]

If you need mathematical typesetting, `\usepackage{unicode-math}` instead of `fontspec` and pick [an OpenType math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) that matches your text font.

Comment: Very nice your answers. +1 surely.

Answer (score 1):

MinionPro and MyriadPro are open-type fonts with latin, cyrillic and greek characters. They are distributed with Adobe Reader, and can easily be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, at least as long as no math is involved.

B.A.

Comment: MnSymbol can be used together MinionPro, I guess.